# This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' and 'number' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Tags: javascript

i am trying to write a conditional statement to set a state to a current value onclick instead i'm getting this feedback:

This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' and 'number' have no overlap.ts(2367)

here is the code:

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Styles } from './style'


const index = () => {
    const [steps, currentStep] = useState<number>([0]);

    const stepper: any {
        if(currentStep == +1){
            return (
                <Text>Step 1</Text>
            )
        }
    }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6'}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff', marginBottom: 10}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[Styles.centerElement, {width: 50, height: 50}]} onPress={() => {}}>
            <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back" size={25} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={[Styles.centerElement, {height: 50}]}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#000'}}>Create A New Event</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    </View>
  )
};

export default index

const styles = StyleSheet.create({}```
````